# jQuery UI autocomplete bring data from a json file

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm really struggling trying to use the jQuery UI autocomplete plugin. I've had a look at a few demos but I still can't seem to get it to work properly. What I want to do is bring the data from my json file called destination.json.

This is what I have so far:

```
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({ 
    source: function(request, response) { 
        $.ajax({ 
            url: "data/destination.json", 
            dataType: "json", 
            success: function( data ) { 
                response(data.destinations); 
            } 
        }); 
    } 
});
```

& the HTML

```
<div class="left">Destination</div>
<div class="right"><input name="autocomplete" type="text" size="27" id="autocomplete"/></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

& the JSON

```
{
"destinations": [
    {
        "value": "Oceania and Australia",
        "label": "Australia & South Pacific"
    },
    {
        "value": "Australia",
        "label": "Australia"
    },
    {
        "value": "Brisbane",
        "label": "Brisbane-Australia"
    },
    {
        "value": "GoldCoast",
        "label": "GoldCoast-Australia"
    },
    {
        "value": "SunshineCoast",
        "label": "SunshineCoast-Australia"
    } 
 ]
}
```

Comment: What happens with this code? Do you see any error in the console?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What happens when you run the ajax function on it's own? is it return anything?

Comment: I don't see any code for sending data to json file and response function!!

Comment: I don't see any errors... but I'm also not too sure how to use jquery UI autocomplete! or json... How do I send data to the json file?

Comment: Please show what's inside JSON file and please tell me you didn't forget _$(document).ready(function(){_

Comment: I've updated above with some of the json file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The source can point directly to a URL that will give a JSON response.

```
$("#ac").autocomplete({
    source: "data/destination.json",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.item) {
            // do something on successful select of an item
        }
    }
});
```

Oh, and the json response has to be in a specific format.

```
[{
    "id": 1234,
    "label": "Australia & South Pacific",
    "value": "Oceania and Australia",
    "extrastuff1": "hello",
    "extrastuff2": "jin"
}, {...}]
```

I think you get id, label, value. Just FYI, you can also send back extra information and access it in javascript like `$("#log").html(ui.item.extrastuff1);`

Comment: I'm still a little bit confused as to what that means.. sorry i really haven't had much experience with this and im finding tutorials to not be very helpful

Comment: so label and value aren't enough?

Comment: label and value should be enough. maybe id is required. extrastuff1/2 or whatever else is completely optional. Btw, data/destination.json is a static file right?

Comment: I believe it is... I'm still really confused as to what I need to do :( Do I need a php file? I'm noticing a lot of the tutorials seem to link to a php file rather than a .json file...

Comment: Should I link to a php file that links to a .json file?

Comment: `json`? that is an array of objects?